# How to scrape webpage that produce updated data table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a simple Python code for website Scraper using maybe w/ beautiful soup.

The website is an [earthquake monitoring site](https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#8/36.412/140.021/&elem=int&contents=earthquake_map&lang=en), it seems quite complicated and integrated with geo map, but I'm only interested in one of its table info that will only update when the earthquake strikes (or prediction is made), the information I need is in lower right corner, under "More" button where one can choose a specific city of interest.

the thing I want to do is, **scraping** this information, checking if there's any update on the latest info, if the "Maximum seismic intensity in target Pref./City" Column is updated with a number bigger than 4 (the most recent data on top row), I want the code to be able to return a true/false boolean output.(so I can use code module in LabView control an instrument)

Can anyone help me on this matter?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Well, thanks @David K for point out my awful language mistake, lesson learned, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site is dynamic, as it uses a script to query an endpoint and populate the table with the data returned. As such, you can either use a browser manipulation tool like `selenium` to access the page or query the endpoint and parse the JSON response yourself:

```
import requests, json
data = json.loads(requests.get('https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/quake/data/list.json?__time__=202107300300').text)
result = [{'observed':i['at'], 'region':i['en_anm'], 'magnitude':i['mag'], 'max intensity':i['maxi']} for i in data]
```

Output (first ten rows of `result`):

```
[{'observed': '2021-07-30T03:48:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Iwate Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.7', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-30T03:26:00+09:00', 'region': 'Southern Kyoto Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.6', 'max intensity': '3'}, {'observed': '2021-07-30T03:26:00+09:00', 'region': 'Southern Kyoto Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.6', 'max intensity': ''}, {'observed': '2021-07-30T03:26:00+09:00', 'region': '', 'magnitude': '', 'max intensity': '3'}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T21:22:00+09:00', 'region': 'Adjacent Sea of\u200b Chichijima Island', 'magnitude': '4.2', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T21:17:00+09:00', 'region': 'Adjacent Sea of\u200b Chichijima Island', 'magnitude': '4.1', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T18:57:00+09:00', 'region': 'Adjacent Sea of Tokara Islands', 'magnitude': '2.0', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T18:52:00+09:00', 'region': 'Adjacent Sea of Tokara Islands', 'magnitude': '2.8', 'max intensity': '2'}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T15:16:00+09:00', 'region': 'Aleutian Islands', 'magnitude': '8.2', 'max intensity': ''}, {'observed': '2021-07-29T16:17:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.1', 'max intensity': '1'}]
```

Edit: extracting data for a specific area:

```
vals = [i for i in result if 'Ibaraki Prefecture' in i['region']]
```

Output:

```
[{'observed': '2021-07-29T16:17:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.1', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-28T01:52:00+09:00', 'region': 'Southern Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.4', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-28T00:55:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.5', 'max intensity': '3'}, {'observed': '2021-07-28T00:55:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.5', 'max intensity': ''}, {'observed': '2021-07-27T13:39:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.0', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-23T09:59:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.8', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-23T03:15:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.7', 'max intensity': '2'}, {'observed': '2021-07-20T15:56:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.6', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-15T05:17:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '3.1', 'max intensity': '1'}, {'observed': '2021-07-04T15:35:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.2', 'max intensity': '3'}, {'observed': '2021-07-04T15:35:00+09:00', 'region': 'Off the Coast of Ibaraki Prefecture', 'magnitude': '4.2', 'max intensity': ''}]
```

Edit: to send requests from your restricted network environment via the provided proxy, you can pass the proxy info via the `proxies` parameter of `requests.get`:

```
import requests
proxies = {"https":"https://10.10.1.11:1080"} #example of https proxy
data = json.loads(requests.get('https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/quake/data/list.json?__time__=202107300300',
       proxies = proxies).text)
```

Alternatively, you can use a browser manipulation tool like [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load the page and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the page source:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/map.html#8/36.412/140.021/&elem=int&contents=earthquake_map&lang=en')
tbl = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').select_one('.contents-block table')
hds = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in tbl.select('tr.contents-title th')]
full_table = [dict(zip(hds, [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in b.select('td')])) for b in tbl.select('tr.contents-title ~ tr')]
```

Output (first ten rows of `full_table`):

```
[{'Observed at (JST)': '09:37 JST 02 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Eastern Shimane Prefecture', 'Depth': '10 km', 'Magnitude': '4.3', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '4'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '00:56 JST 02 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Southern Miyagi Prefecture', 'Depth': '10 km', 'Magnitude': '2.3', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '1'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '22:50 JST 01 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Hamadori, Fukushima Prefecture', 'Depth': '100 km', 'Magnitude': '3.9', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '2'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '16:53 JST 01 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Adjacent Sea of Okinawa Main Island', 'Depth': '30 km', 'Magnitude': '4.1', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '2'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '12:18 JST 01 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Adjacent Sea of\u200b Miyakojima Island', 'Depth': '30 km', 'Magnitude': '3.9', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '1'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '09:44 JST 01 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Southern Nagano Prefecture', 'Depth': '10 km', 'Magnitude': '2.1', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '1'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '02:18 JST 01 Aug. 2021', 'Region name': 'Off the east Coast of Hokkaido', 'Depth': '30 km', 'Magnitude': '3.6', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '1'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '20:04 JST 31 Jul. 2021', 'Region name': 'Off the Coast of Iwate Prefecture', 'Depth': '50 km', 'Magnitude': '3.4', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '1'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '14:26 JST 31 Jul. 2021', 'Region name': 'Southern Sorachi Region, Hokkaido', 'Depth': '180 km', 'Magnitude': '5.0', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '2'}, {'Observed at (JST)': '13:09 JST 31 Jul. 2021', 'Region name': 'Southern Tokushima Prefecture', 'Depth': '50 km', 'Magnitude': '4.5', 'Maximumseismicintensity(JMASeismicIntensity)': '3'}]
```

Comment: Hi, @Ajax1234 thanks so much for help! I'm not so much a expert in web scrapping, but I get the basic idea of your code, seems terrific!
I'm just wondering, how did you get the url ('https://www.jma.go.jp/bosai/quake/data/list.json?__time__=202107300300') ?
It's an endpoint JSON strings for which prefecture? because I only need a earthquake data for "Tsukuba City / Ibaraki Prefecture" Can you help me with the corresponding url link? (I only know the webpage of the table data I want is in here www.jma.go.jp/bosai/#pattern=earthquake_volcano&area_type=offices&area_code=080000)

Comment: @Maggie The endpoint link can be found by loading the developer tools (right-click => inspect) and clicking on the "network" tab. Please see my recent edit, as I added a way to grab the Ibaraki Prefecture data.

Comment: I tried the code in our institute network environment, it seems we have some kinda high-level security setting in our network, so the endpoint link in the script can not be accessed, Python it's throwing a "SSL Error" ....

Comment: Hi @Ajax , The code runs perfect at my home network environment. But I'm also working in a restricted network environment inside a national lab. (We are only accessing outside website thru some web proxy.) So whenever I run the script, the error thrown is
`ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))` I'm guessing, the requests.get() should have some further ability to fix a proxy problem?

Comment: @Maggie Sorry for the late response, please see my recent edit, as I added a couple of options (including a proxy-based solution for `requests`) to solve the problem.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks so much!! Now everything works perfectly!

Comment: @Maggie Glad to help!